# Eaccess file permisson denied still showing after using sudo chown

Tags: macos, terminal, yeoman, sudo, chown

Hi all am trying to use yeoman angular generator but after hitting 'yo angular' it always shows

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/UI-Developer/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml'
```

even i tried

```
sudo chown UI-Developer:staff /Users/UI-Developer/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml
```

here UI-Developer is User ID and staff is group name on my MAC mavericks always showing error the url was correct.help me out

Comment: What is the file-mode of that file?

Comment: @trojanfoe How do i know about `file-mode` i dont know about it

Comment: use `ls -l /path/to/file` and update your question with the output.

Comment: @trojanfoe this is the output after list `ls -l insight-yo.yml
----rw-rw-  1 UI-Developer  staff  37 Jul  8 18:21 insight-yo.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it's the file mode, which is:

```
----rw-rw-
 ^^^^^^^^^
 uuugggooo
```

Where `u` = user, `g` = group and `o` = other.

Which means `user` (you) has no access.

Fix with:

```
sudo chmod 0644 /Users/UI-Developer/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml
```